# Перенос значений из списка в другой класс

Tags: java, jsoup

Собственно сабж.В отдельном классе парсю страницу,в другом создаю GUI.Требуется передать результат парсинга (цикла) в JTextArea.Джаву изучаю вторую неделю,прошу тапками не бросаться.Парсинг:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class parseClass {

public void go() throws Exception {


    List<Article> articleList=new ArrayList<>();

    Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://4pda.ru").get();

    Elements 
    divelements=doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("itemprop","description");

    divelements.forEach(divelement -> {
       Element pElement=divelement.child(0);
      // String url=pElement.attr("style");
       String title=pElement.text();

       articleList.add(new Article(null,title));

    });

    articleList.forEach(System.out::println);

}
public ArrayList<String> getTextList(){
    ArrayList<String> textList=new ArrayList<String>(); 

    return textList;
}
}



}
class Article{

private String url;
private String name;



public Article(String url, String name) {

    this.url = url;
    this.name = name;
}
public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}
public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return  "Text= "+name + '\n' ;
}

}
```

GUI:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import javafx.stage.Screen;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class guiParse {

 JLabel label;
  JFrame frame;
JTextArea jt;
  JScrollPane scroll;

public void gui() {
    label=new JLabel("text");
    jt=new JTextArea(16,58);
    jt.setText("kakoy to text");
    jt.setEditable(false);
    frame =new JFrame();
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    scroll= new JScrollPane(jt);
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panel.add(scroll);
    frame.add(panel);


    //frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,);
    frame.setTitle("Future App");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


}
```

main:

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import javafx.stage.Screen;

 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
 import java.awt.Label;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 class jSoupTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    parseClass parse=new parseClass();
    parse.go();


    guiParse gui=new guiParse();
    gui.gui();

}
```

}

То есть вызов в отдельности есть,не могу передать.Со списками особо не работал,по сути применяю впервые,просто передать по параметру String в gui само собой не вышло.Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте в `parseClass` метод, который будет возвращать `articleList`. Просто добавьте:

```
return articleList;
```

вместо:

```
articleList.forEach(System.out::println);
```

В `guiParse` создайте переменную `List<Article> articleList` и конструктор, принимающий этот список на вход:

```
public guiParse(List<Article> articleList){
    this.articleList = articleList;
}
```

В своём `main()` передавайте результат функции`articleList` на вход конструктора и уже в методе `gui()` читайте оттуда результат.

Comment: Благодарю за напутствие,все работает.Скажите,при чтении из конструктора можно и передать в jt.seText() напрямую articleList? При конвертации в String  все ок,просто интересно есть ли прямой способ

Answer (score 1):

```
class jSoupTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new guiParse().gui(new parseClass().go());
    }
}


import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class guiParse {

    JLabel label;
    JFrame frame;
    JTextArea jt;
    JScrollPane scroll;

    public void gui(List <Article> articleList) {
        label = new JLabel("text");
        jt = new JTextArea(16, 58);
        jt.setText(namesFromArticleList(articleList));
        jt.setEditable(false);
        frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        scroll = new JScrollPane(jt);
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel.add(scroll);
        frame.add(panel);

        //frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,);
        frame.setTitle("Future App");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public String namesFromArticleList(List <Article> articleList) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Article article : articleList) sb.append(article.getName()).append("\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }

}



class Article {

    private String url;
    private String name;

    public Article(String url, String name) {

        this.url = url;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Text= " + name + '\n';
    }

}


import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class parseClass {

    public List<Article> go() throws Exception {

        List<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<>();

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://4pda.ru").get();

        Elements divelements = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("itemprop", "description");

        divelements.forEach(divelement -> {
            Element pElement = divelement.child(0);
            // String url=pElement.attr("style");
            String title = pElement.text();

            articleList.add(new Article(null, title));

        });
        return articleList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Размеры текстового поля уже сами подгоняйте. И запомните, что за именование классов с маленькой буквы бьют долго и сильно. и еще, если есть смысл выносить переменную,как переменную класса, то она в 99,9 процентах случаев должна быть с модификатором private. а если нужен доступ извне, то через геттеры и сеттеры.